# how to pass map-canvas as string instead of getting it from document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

Is there a way to pass a string variable like the following:

```
var mapCanvas = '<div id="map-canvas"></div>';
```

into

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas,mapOptions);
```

In my case this is giving me errors, because i am dinamically generating my pages, with this i mean that i only have one div in my body, generate maps and everything and then i append them to my div. but when i do this i am having errors in the google maps itself. errors like position is undefined. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
google.maps.Map
```

Needs a DOM object, so you can first add #map-canvas to the body, and then use it in your google map initialization code.

```
$("body").append('<div id="map-canvas"></div>');
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
```

I use JQuery library in this example for appending DIV to Body:`$("body").append()`

Comment: Yes, it would. But the parent DIV should be exist in your page before using append.